# Java Spring jaxb webServiceTemplate

Tags: spring, jaxb, unmarshalling

My question is simple.

for Unmarshalling i want to write custom unmarshaller but for marshelling i have wsdl

I have following method which returns unmarshalled object but i want xml string to use with my unmarshal object please quick help needed.

```
Bean wsdlBean = (wsdlBean)webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(results);
```

I want some thing like this

```
String xmlStr = webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(results);
```

how can I acheive this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `WebServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(Source source, Result result)` - API is [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/client/core/WebServiceTemplate.html#sendSourceAndReceiveToResult%28javax.xml.transform.Source,%20javax.xml.transform.Result%29);

Just define your Result as StringResult, and Source as StringSource:

```
StringSource source = new StringSource(content);
StringResult result = new StringResult(new StringWriter());

wsTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(source, result);

..result.getWriter().toString();
```

Comment: also check out this http://gleichmann.wordpress.com/2008/02/24/flexible-marshalling-and-unmarshalling-using-spring-ws/